# how to make hyperlinkfield unclickable based on other column value in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a column name Status. if status value= Approved then make hyperlinkfield unclickable, named Edit

ASPX.Code:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField   DataNavigateUrlFields="Trasaction_Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="TransactionForm.aspx?id={0}"
                            HeaderText="Edit" Text="<img src='../images/edit-9.png' />" />
```

CodeBehind

```
protected void gdvReview_RowDataBound(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentUserSession = (UserSession)Session["UserSession"];
        if (currentUserSession == null) return;
        var roleID = currentUserSession.RoleId;

        if(roleID==3)
        {
           if (e.Row.Cells[10].Text.Trim()=="Approved")
                {
                    var hyperlink = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("Edit");
                    hyperlink.Attributes.Add("onclick","return false");
                }


        }


    }
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

just disable the hyperlink. so instead of

```
hyperlink.Attributes.Add("onclick","return false");
```

use

```
hyperlink.Enabled = false;
```

and your hyperlink becomes un-clickable